# Can I send native token in the contract just after deployment by calling the constructor on Ink smart contract?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Is it possible to transmit the native token to the contract immediately after deployment by invoking the constructor on the [Ink](https://use.ink/) smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the constructor [payable](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/b5a5a554f85e9bd07d288ab319d14f15e6e509af/contract-transfer/lib.rs#L16)